# Will Counterbalance counter storm copies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Counterbalance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Counterbalance) allows you to reveal the top card of your library whenever a spell is played, and counter it if the revealed card has the same mana cost.

If an opponent has cast several spells to ramp up to casting [Tendrils of Agony](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tendrils%20of%20Agony), and I have [Helm of Obedience](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20Obedience) on top of my library, **do I get to counter all of the storm copies?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, Counterbalance only counters the original Storm spell.**

> 706.10. To copy a spell or activated ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; a copy of a spell isn’t cast and a copy of an activated ability isn’t activated. [...]

Since the copies are not cast, Counterbalance never triggers for them.